# Typescript: 'this' when extending abstract class

Tags: typescript

So my issue is pretty straight forward. I have the following code:

```js
abstract class A {
  public abstract fn(): this;
}

class B extends A {
  public fn() {
    return new B();
  }
}
```

which is supposed to mean that whichever class inherits from A is supposed to return an instance of itself when `fn` is called but running this code I get an error:  `Property 'fn' in type 'B' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'A'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error you are getting is cause by the fact that you don't have an annotation on `fn`  in `B`.This means `fn` will return `B` not `this` in the derived class.

The only value you can really return (without type assertions) from a function returning `this` is `this`. Consider the following:

```
abstract class A {
    public abstract fn(): this;
}

class B extends A {
    public fn(): this {
        return new B();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    m() { }
}
new C().fn().m(); // runtime error since fn returned B instead of C
```

You can use a type assertion but it is not really type safe as demonstrated above:

```
class B extends A {
    public fn(): this {
        return new B() as this;
    }
}
```

Comment: That was a great explanation, thanks a lot! I guess I will have to change the structure of my code since, as you said, there is not a good type-safe way of achieving what I want. Will also accept the answer once SO lets me.

Comment: @Komninos you want to correctly type a `clone` function basically. I don't think there is a good way to model this in typescript. The function would have to be typed in such a way that all derived types must override it, `abstract` will only make you override the first level classes ..

Answer (score 2):

Titian explained why it is not allowed. Here's how you can implement it in safer way:

```
abstract class A<T> {
    public abstract fn(): T;
}

class B extends A<B> {
    public fn() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is type safe, but suffers from the inability to extend it past `B` :(

Answer (score 0):

But you're not returning and instance of itself, you're returning a new instance:

```
abstract class A {
  public abstract fn(): this;
}

class B extends A {
  public fn() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Or change return:

```
abstract class A {
  public abstract fn(): A;
}

class B extends A {
  public fn() {
    return new B();;
  }
}
```